# VB Error - Object doesnt support this property or method

Tags: vba, excel

I am at a very basic part of VB and I am stuck with this relentless issue. I am trying to copy data from a form to a bunch of cells in excel and I am facing this error.

Object doesn't support this property or method: Runtime Error - 438

Although the first row gets inserted. The issue is with the second row. I don't see the problem. Kindly help

```
Sub sbInsertingRows()
Range("A3").EntireRow.Insert
End Sub


Sub EditAdd()

sbInsertingRows

Cells(3, 19).Value = Order_Details_Form.Controls(TextBox_orderid).Value
Cells(3, 20).Value = Order_Details_Form.Controls(TextBox_name).Value
Cells(3, 24).Value = Order_Details_Form.Controls(TextBox2).Value

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

EditAdd gets called on click

Comment: Can you write `debug.pring Order_Details_Form.Controls(TextBox_name).Value` before the line that gives the error?

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: Please do not spam tags: those are all very, very different incarnations of VB.  Hold your mouse over them. read the words and remove the ones that do not apply.  Also you should read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I'm voting to close as *unclear what you're asking*, because it's unclear where the error is being raised from, and what "the second row" means or stands for.

Comment: Query resolved by Fadi's answer.

Comment: And sorry about the ambiguous query. Will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

I think `TextBox_orderid` is a name of your textbox control not a variable so you should enclose it  with `"` like:

```
Cells(3, 19).Value = Order_Details_Form.Controls("TextBox_orderid").Value
```

Or you can simply use:

```
Cells(3, 19).Value = Order_Details_Form.TextBox_orderid.Value
```

Apply this at your other two lines.

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly well. :)